# Finding Count of Duplicate emails that has a different first and/or last name

Tags: sql

Hi I'm having trouble getting the right count for this problem. I'm trying to get a count of duplicate email that has a different first name and/or different last name.
(i.e 
123@.com sam
123@.com ben
I need a count of that duplicate email)
I'm working with 2 tables. The email_address is in the mrtcustomer.customer_email table and the first and last name is in the mrtcustomer.customer_master table

My code

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(SELECT e.customer_master_id, email_address, customer_first_name, customer_last_name, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EMAIL_ADDRESS ORDER BY CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME) RN
FROM mrtcustomer.customer_email e 
JOIN mrtcustomer.customer_master t ON e.customer_master_id = t.customer_master_id
WHERE t.customer_first_name IS NOT NULL 
AND t.customer_last_name IS NOT NULL 
AND customer_FIRST_NAME != 'Unknown' 
AND customer_LAST_NAME != 'Unknown' 
GROUP BY e.customer_master_id, email_address, customer_first_name, customer_last_name 
ORDER BY 1 DESC) 
WHERE RN > 1
```

I'm guessing its my WHERE clause that is wrong.

Comment: Would NULL and another value count as a duplicate?

Comment: Try simplifying the problem.  Your `WHERE t.customer_first_name... AND... AND...` clause is your business logic, not related to the question asked. Is the join necessary to see the problem or are the e-mail addresses and customer names from different tables?

Comment: the join is necessary because the email is in the mrtcustomer.customer_email table and the first and last name is in the mrtcustomer.customer_master table. My where clause is really messy. I don't know how to write it out so that I can get count of duplicate email where first and last name is different.

Comment: Null and another value would count as a duplicate as long as the email is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would start with something like this: **(edited to reflect edits)**

```
select email_address
    , count( distinct customer_first_name ) f
    , count( distinct customer_last_name ) l
from customer_email e, customar_master m
where e.customer_master_id = m.customer_master_id
group by email_address
```

then if either of the name columns is > 1 you have a problem - so wrap that similar to this:

```
select email_address from
(
select email_address
    , count( distinct customer_first_name ) f
    , count( distinct customer_last_name ) l
from customer_email e, customar_master m
where e.customer_master_id = m.customer_master_id
group by email_address
)
where fn > 1 or ln > 1
```

Comment: I'm working with 2 tables, the email is in the email table and the names is in another table. It get really confusing.

Answer (score 0):

identify distinct fname,lname,email records...
then group by email (having more than one record)...
then do a count on that.

```
-- count
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT email_address)
FROM 
(
    -- group by email , find where there is more than one distinct record for each email
    SELECT email_address
    FROM 
    (
        -- get distinct Fname, Lname, Email combinations in derived table
        SELECT customer_first_name , customer_last_name, email_address
        FROM mrtcustomer.customer_email 
        JOIN mrtcustomer.customer_master t ON e.customer_master_id = t.customer_master_id
        WHERE t.customer_first_name IS NOT NULL 
        AND t.customer_last_name IS NOT NULL 
        AND customer_FIRST_NAME != 'Unknown' 
        AND customer_LAST_NAME != 'Unknown' 
        GROUP BY 1,2,3
    )  foo
    GROUP BY 1
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
)  bar
```